# SQL query in flask python returning a key error

Tags: python, sql

I'm creating a period tracker on a website. I'm using a SQL database to store user info, and I'm also getting user input on one of my web pages about the length of their menstrual cycle and period. I'm storing the user input in another table. So my problem is, I'm testing to calculate the avg length of a particular user's menstrual cycle, but the query is returning a dictionary when I need an integer. I need it as an integer because I'm using that value for some calculations. When I run the program (I'm using flask in python btw), I get a key error. Do u know how I can solve this?

I have a table timeline with columns uid, prev_period_date, period_length and cycle_length.

```
    cycle_avg = db.execute("SELECT AVG(cycle_length) FROM timeline WHERE uid=:user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["cycle_length"]
    period_avg = db.execute("SELECT AVG(period_length) FROM timeline WHERE uid=:user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["period_length"]
```

The error I get is:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/f_p/application.py", line 167, in tracker
    cycle_avg = db.execute("SELECT AVG(cycle_length) FROM timeline WHERE uid=:user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["cycle_length"]

KeyError: 'cycle_length'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The result set retrieved from your db doesn't contain a field named `cycle_length` because you didn't give an alias to your calculated field. Try:

```
cycle_avg = db.execute("SELECT AVG(cycle_length) as cycle_length FROM timeline WHERE uid=:user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["cycle_length"]
period_avg = db.execute("SELECT AVG(period_length) as period_length FROM timeline WHERE uid=:user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["period_length"]
```